# Why does MATLAB Engine API for C++ leaves "still reachable 8,132 bytes in 99 blocks" even for a simple program with just engine open and close?

Tags: c++, matlab

Following is a section of the output of the log-file from Valgrind using the following command:

> valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --verbose
> --log-file=valgrind_output.txt ./TestMatlab

```
    ==12340== 
    ==12340== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==12340==     in use at exit: 8,132 bytes in 99 blocks
    ==12340==   total heap usage: 3,810 allocs, 3,711 frees, 436,330 bytes allocated
    ==12340== 
    ==12340== Searching for pointers to 99 not-freed blocks
    ==12340== Checked 3,940,672 bytes
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ==12340== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==12340==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==12340==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==12340==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==12340==    still reachable: 8,132 bytes in 99 blocks
    ==12340==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==12340== 
    ==12340== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
    ==12340== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The C++ program is a very simple code that just instantiates an object of the engine API for C++ interface and subsequently closes the engine interface. The code is shown below:

```
#include "engine.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    Engine *ep;

    if (!(ep = engOpen(""))) {
        std::cout <<"\nCan't start MATLAB engine" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    engClose(ep);

    return 0;
}
```

Can this issue be fixed? If so how can I do it?

Comment: "Still reachable" is not leaked memory. This is memory still in use when `main()` terminates. `ep` still points to some object that handles the connection. You closed the connection, but that object still exists, whatever `ep` points to was never freed. This is totally fine, the OS will clean up all memory assigned to your program when it terminates. (NOTE: do not attempt to `free(ep)`, you have no idea what `*ep` is or what other memory blocks it points to.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Ah, I see the pointer ep now is not been freed.

Comment: Actually, I am working on a project and the program size has become quite big now. I encounter **stack smashing detected** when a line engEvalString(ep, "res = sim('model')"); gets executed and if I comment on this line in the project my Valgrind reports the same as "still reachable: 8,132 bytes in 99 blocks with no errors and no lost" and the project runs with no error.

Comment: It's hard to say what that could be from the description you've given. Are you able to run any MATLAB command at all? It is very likely that some earlier code is causing stack corruption, and it's not reported until this moment. Try to create a [mre] for this stack smashing, remove code from your program bit by bit until you have the smallest possible program that still produces this error. This will likely tell you why you're getting this error, or at least will give you a good example to ask a question on SO about.